# Fetching a column data of another table using id Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a table which has a column `interviewer_id` which is equal to the `id` of users table. I am grouping the data according to the `interviewer_id` in my controller and want to fetch the name belongs to the id of each group from the users table. Here is what i tried

```
$int_payment = IntPayments::where('month',$month_year)->groupBy('interviewer_id')->get();
    foreach ($int_payment as $inter) {
        $inters = User::where('id',$inter->interviewer_id)->get();

    }
    return response()->json(['inters',$inters]);
```

Here my response shows only one group data it fetched through User. I want get the row from the users table where its `id` is group's ID

Here is what i exactly want. When i return $int_payment in response i get this response.

```
["inters",[{"id":2,"candidate_id":"13","interviewer_id":"1","profile_id":"","exp":"5-10","payment_status":"unpaid","month":"Feb 2017","created_at":"2017-02-08 04:56:40","updated_at":"2017-02-08 04:56:40"},{"id":4,"candidate_id":"13","interviewer_id":"2\r\n","profile_id":"","exp":"5-10","payment_status":"unpaid","month":"Feb 2017","created_at":"2017-02-08 04:56:40","updated_at":"2017-02-08 04:56:40"},{"id":1,"candidate_id":"13","interviewer_id":"4","profile_id":"","exp":"5-10","payment_status":"unpaid","month":"Feb 2017","created_at":"2017-02-08 04:56:40","updated_at":"2017-02-08 04:56:40"}]]
```

If you see the response there are three groups with ids 2,4 and 1. These ids are id of the user in the user table. I want to get the user's name which belongs to the ids.

Answer (score 3):

Try returning `$inters` in array:

```
foreach ($int_payment as $inter) {
        $inters[] = User::where('id',$inter->interviewer_id)->get();
    }
return $inters;
```

However, setting up relationship between User and IntPayment models will be much easier to handle this kind of situation. See in doc [Eloquent relationship.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: But your answer gets me the data from USER table. But i want only the name column from that table and the data from IntPayments is my first priority. See this. you will understand the scenario better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42129360/merging-different-table-data-into-same-array-in-laravel

Comment: @NaveenKumar learn and use [Eloquent relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) instead of even trying that way. With relationship setup, it will be just one step and one query to acheive what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
IntPayments::select('interviewr_TABLE.*', 'users.name')->where('month',$month_year)->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'interviewr_TABLE') ->groupBy('interviewer_id')->get()
```

The only problem here is I don't know exactly what is your IntPayments table name is.

Comment: Instead of using table name , i am fetching the data with model

Comment: This is a simple leftJoin, there is not any problem in this case, but you can define that left join as a model relationship.

Comment: But your answer gets me the data from USER table. But i want only the name column from that table and the data from IntPayments is my first priority. See this. you will understand the scenario better  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42129360/merging-different-table-data-into-same-array-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Laravel model relationship to make life easier:

Make you `User` Model have:

```
public function intpayments(){
    $this->hasMany(IntPayments::class, 'interviewer_id');
}
```

Then your `IntPayments` model have:

```
public function user(){
    $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'interviewer_id');
}
```

So you can easily retrieve the same result you want with:

```
$inters = IntPayments::where('month',$month_year)->load('user');
```

Then you can loop through this result to get the fields you need say:

```
$result = [];
    foreach($inters as $inter)
    {
       $result[] = $inter->user->name;
    }
return $result;
```

**UPDATED:**

> But i want only the name column from that table and the data from IntPayments is my first priority

Okay so you can still use the same result returned from the query:

```
$result = [];
    foreach($inters as $k => $inter)
    {
       $result[$k]['name'] = $inter->user->name; //this is the user's name
       $result[$k]['id'] = $inter->id; //this is intPayments's id
       $result[$k]['interviewer_id'] = $inter->interviewer_id; //this is intPayments interviewer's 'id
       ......
    }
```

Maybe you don't know, the result from the `$inters` variable would give you first, each record from `IntPayments` then with the `User` for each of them.

This means that `inters` will be naturally like (if I send the response as json):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "candidate_id": "1",
    "interviewer_id": "3"
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "second last",
      "email": "second@somemail.com",
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "candidate_id": "1",
    "interviewer_id": "5",
    "user": {
    "id": 1,
      "name": "first last",
      "email": "first@somemail.com",
    }
  },
  .....
]
```

This means you can use this response as you wish and access the fields you want.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: But your answer gets me the data from USER table. But i want only the name column from that table and the data from IntPayments is my first priority. See this. you will understand the scenario better  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42129360/merging-different-table-data-into-same-array-in-laravel