# merging different table data into same array in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

I want to get different table data and save them in array.

```
$int_payment = IntPayments::where('month',$month_year)->groupBy('interviewer_id')->get();

    foreach ($int_payment as $inter) {
        $inters[] = User::where('id',$inter->interviewer_id)->get();
        $inters['payment_status'] = $inter->payment_status;

    }
    return response()->json(['inters'=>$inters,'month'=>$month]);
```

Here i am fetching the name of the user in user's table from interviewer_id which is from int_payment table. Now the `$inters[]` has all the data of the particular user. Now i want to fetch only one column from the int_payments table and add it to the array $inters. The above code doesn't work as expected. it results this. The above code also adds the the payment status to the first array value and not to the other array values. like this

```
{"inters":{"0":[{"id":1,"name":"Naveen1","phone":"7841237900",}],"payment_status":"unpaid","1":[{"id":2,"name":"john","phone":"7845123900",}]}}

{"inters":{"0":[{"id":1,"name":"Naveen1"}],"payment_status":"unpaid",}
```

But i want it to be include inside the array like this

```
{"inters":{"0":[{"id":1,"name":"Naveen1","payment_status":"unpaid"}],}
{"inters":{"1":[{"id":2,"name":"john","payment_status":"paid"}],}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly that you want to have something like this:

```
{"inters":{"0":[{"id":1,"name":"Naveen1","payment_status":"unpaid"}],}
```

The perhaps using `push` on the collection you have would be helpful as:

```
$int_payment = IntPayments::where('month',$month_year)->groupBy('interviewer_id')->get();

foreach ($int_payment as $key => $inter) {
    $inters = User::where('id',$inter->interviewer_id)->get(['id', 'name']);
    $inters_payment[] = $inters->push(['payment_status' => $inter->payment_status]);
}

return response()->json(['inters'=>$inters_payment,'month'=>$month]);
```

By the way, I don't know where this `$month` variable will feature, but I just left it as you have in your example code.

One warning however, is that why not adopt laravel's relationship to cater for the interaction between the `User` and `IntPayments` model? Because as I could observe, if you have thousands of `IntPayments` returned, then just for this function, you would be performing thousands of query on `users` table.

You could have something simple and elegant as this:

```
$inters = IntPayments::where('month',$month_year)->groupBy('interviewer_id')->with('user')->get();
    $result = [];
    foreach($inters as $key => $inter)
    {
       $result[$key]['id'] = $inter->user->id;
       $result[$key]['name'] = $inter->user->name;
       $result[$key]['payment_status'] = $inter->payment_status;
    }
```

Then you can have your response as:

```
return response()->json(['inters'=> $result]);
```